# Copy current document to another location in V/Vim

Tags: vim, copy

Im wondering if there is a command in V/Vim that will save a backup of the current document to another location (e.g., from C:\ to C:\backup). Any subsequent write with the ":w" command will still write to the old location (e.g., C:).

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: That's the default behaviour of the :w command.

Comment: You already got the right answer, but I'll add this because I was surprised by the behaviour of the `:w[rite] <filename>` command. To write to a new location so that subsequent writes use the new location, you use the `:sav[eas] <filename>` command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify a file name after `:w`:

```
:w /tmp/backup.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

The following will write a copy of the current file being edited to foo.txt:

```
:w foo.txt
```